# how to add available COM ports to ComboBox useing C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

i want to add available COM ports of the computer to combobox using C#. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you: [`SerialPort.GetPortNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx)